# Using json_decode on a JSON feed containing Cyrillic characters

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to decode a JSON feed containing some Cyrillic characters. Not all of the characters in the feed is Cyrillic though. I'm using json_decode which works fine for anything else, but return garbage when there are Cyrillic characters.

The results look like this: Ð”ÐµÑ„Ñ„Ð°Ñ‡ÐºÐ¸

Any ideas?

Comment: There are no cyrillic characters. There are certain **encodings**. You are trying to output utf-8 encoded text using single-byte encoding. Use utf-8 instead

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. Turns out adding "<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />" to the head of my page resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page is being decoded as CP1252 when it's actually UTF-8. Set your headers properly.

```
>>> print u'Ð”ÐµÑ„Ñ„Ð°Ñ‡ÐºÐ¸'.encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8')
Деффачки
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can not decode unicode characters with json_decode, use addslashes() while using json_encode. The problem comes from unicode chars starting with \ such as \u30d7

`$json_data = addslashes(json_encode($unicode_string_or_array));`

Answer (score 0):

hermanschutte Use the **escape** function when sending data through javascript